# Evaluate the improper integral: $\int_o^\infty 1.35 \times 10^{-7} e^{-0.03x}x^4 dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the improper integral:
> $$\int_0^\infty 1.35 \times 10^{-7} e^{-0.03x}x^4  dx$$
> (Needed for a solid processing example in chemical engineering).

Now according to my textbook, this is simply $4/0.03$.

Anyone have a clue as to how they determined this?

Comment: Are you sure? I additionally used wolfram alpha to check this result for me and it is correct I believe

Comment: Hint: Gamma function:$$24=4!=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^4~{\rm d}t$$where $t=0.03x$

Comment: The Laplace Transform of $x^n$ is $\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involves the gamma function...

[image]

Comment: You have a couple of mistakes, but you have a image instead of latex code.

Comment: Here's the equations from latex. 
$$u = ax$$
$$x = \frac{u}{a}$$
$$dx = \frac{du}{a}$$

\begin{equation}c\int_0^\infty {e^{ - ax}{x^n}dx} = c\int_0^\infty {{e^{ - u}}{{\left( {\frac{u}{a}} \right)}^n}\frac{{du}}{a}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c\int_0^\infty {{e^{ - ax}}{x^n}dx} = \frac{c}{{{a^{n + 1}}}}\int_0^\infty {{e^{ - u}}{u^n}du} = \frac{c}{{{a^{n + 1}}}} \underbrace {\int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - u}}{u^n}du} }_{n!}\end{equation}
$$c\int_0^\infty {{e^{ - ax}}{x^n}dx} = \frac{c}{{{a^{n + 1}}}}n!$$

Comment: The gamma function evaluated in n, is not the factorial of n. $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$

Comment: You have to use latex code instead of images in your answer in order to let the community to revise you answer if required.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid. Use integration by parts.
$$\int_0^\infty 1.35 \times 10^{-7} e^{-0.03x}x^4  dx= 1.35 \times 10^{-7}\int_0^\infty e^{-0.03x}x^4  dx=
\\ 
1.35 \times 10^{-7} \\\left( e^{(-0.03 x)} \big(-33.3333 x^4 - 4444.44 x^3 - 444444. x^2 - 2.96296×10^7 x - 9.87654×10^8\big) \Bigg\vert _0^\infty \right)$$

Then, you can use L'Hôpital's rule to compute the limit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}\\\displaystyle
\int_0^\infty a e^{-bx}x^n  dx
&=\dfrac{a}{b}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty  e^{-y}(y/b)^n  dy
\qquad y = bx, dx = dy/b\\
&=\dfrac{a}{b^{n+1}}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty  e^{-y}y^n  dy\\
&=\dfrac{an!}{b^{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$$

For
$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty 1.35 \times 10^{-7} e^{-0.03x}x^4  dx
$,
$a=1.35 \times 10^{-7},
b=0.03,
n=4
$
so the result is
$\dfrac{an!}{b^{n+1}}
=\dfrac{4!1.35 \times 10^{-7}}{0.03^5}
=133\frac13
$
according to Wolfy.